# Unable to use Zend\I18n\View\Helper\CurrencyFormat class

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm trying to implement the CurrencyFormat Helper, but when I instance and object of CurrencyFormat the application is raising an exeption:

```
$var new CurrencyFormat();

File:
/site/vendor/zendframework/zend-i18n/Zend/I18n/View/Helper/CurrencyFormat.php                    :63
Message:
Zend\I18n\View\Helper component requires the intl PHP extension
```

In my controller I'm including the library

```
use Zend\I18n\View\Helper\CurrencyFormat;
```

I guess I need to add something in composer.json or config files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. The component requires the [intl PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php). This is something that is (usually) bundled with PHP and needs to be enabled on your server.