# Zend InputFilter requires intl PHP extension?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am setting up some filters and validators for my form, but when I submit it, this error appears: "Zend\I18n\Filter component requires the intl PHP extension". Is this because of the Alnum and Alpha validators ?

Code:

```
     public function getInputFilter() {
        if (!$this->inputFilter) {
            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

            $inputFilter->add(array(
                'name' => 'email',
                'required' => true,
                "filters" => array(
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    array('name' => 'StripTags')),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Regex',
                        'options' => array(
                            'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/',
                            'messages' => array(
                                Regex::NOT_MATCH => 'Е-майл адреса е невалиден.',
                            ),
                        ),
                        'break_chain_on_failure' => true
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'EmailAddress',
                        'options' => array(
                            'messages' => array(
                                EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT => "Е-майл адреса е невалиден.",
                                EmailAddress::INVALID => "",
                                EmailAddress::INVALID_LOCAL_PART => "",
                                EmailAddress::INVALID_HOSTNAME => "",
                                EmailAddress::INVALID_SEGMENT => "",
                                EmailAddress::DOT_ATOM => "",
                                EmailAddress::INVALID_MX_RECORD => "",
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ));

            $inputFilter->add((array(
                'name' => 'name',
                'required' => true,
                "filters" => array(
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    array('name' => 'StripTags')),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Alpha',
                    ),
                ),
            )));

            $inputFilter->add((array(
                'name' => 'password',
                'required' => true,
                "filters" => array(
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    array('name' => 'StripTags')),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Alnum',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'min' => 6,
                            'max' => 12,
                            'messages' => array(
                                StringLength::INVALID => "Паролата трябва да е от 6 до 12 символа",
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )));
          }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to use Zend\I18n\View\Helper\CurrencyFormat class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771519/unable-to-use-zend-i18n-view-helper-currencyformat-class)

Comment: @Milen can you answer the question then? Please don't leave it unanswered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed it by going to php.ini and uncommenting `extension=php_intl.dll`

Comment: for Windows users only

Comment: Possibly will need to install php*-intl.
See https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/issues/4879 for more details.  Supposedly fixed, but still an issue Nov 2016.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 16.04, with php 5.6, try:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-intl
```

and then

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04, with PHP 7.2, try:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-intl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If don't works enable extension=php_intl.dll in:

```
vim /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XAMPP on MAC OS X add `extension=intl.so` into your `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini` file and restart Apache.
If it is still not working you need to install intl.
You can follow the instruction here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32404183/3303055